# RegEx to remove text not inside parentheses

Tags: regex, pcre, bbedit

How can I remove text that is *not* in between parentheses? This [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nF7hC8/33) selects text inside of parentheses. I'm using BBEdit and the PCRE engine.

Convert:

```
AFGHANISTAN (AF)
LAND ISLANDS (AX)
ALBANIA (AL)
ALGERIA (DZ)
AMERICAN SAMOA (AS)
ANDORRA (AD)
ANGOLA (AO)
```

To:

```
(AF)
(AX)
(AL)
(DZ)
(AS)
(AD)
(AO)
```

Comment: `I need to do the opposite` - no, you need just that. Just keep that text in parentheses and discard the original text.

Comment: Which language or regex engine?

Comment: @ctwheels The text editor BBEdit which uses PCRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
.*?(\([^)]*\))
```

and replace with `$1`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nF7hC8/34)

Comment: TIL: better regex-based bounds-matching by using the exclusion operator `[^)]` in conjunction with the later `*\)` to robustly match between `(` and `)`

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the [List of sovereign states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states), aside of upper-case letters, there should also appear `-` and `'` characters (example "*Cote d'Ivoire*" (might also be "*Ivory Coast*") and "*Guinea-Bissau*") therefore `\w` shall rather not be used. I'd go for a bit strict [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/CjbcIT/3):

```
[A-Z'\- ]+ (\([A-Z'-]{2}\))
```

A loose variant of the one above is [this one](https://regex101.com/r/UUnIKb/3):

```
.* (\(..\))
```

Comment: For some reason, maybe because I'm using BBEdit, this removes everything or replaces all with $1

Comment: Then use `\1` instead :) I posted a general Regex answer.